# Redux mapStateToProps to class react component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i have this code

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

class GroupsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return();
}
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  groups: selectGroups
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GroupsPage);
```

My question is, how could i get the groups object from mapStateToProps into the GroupsPage component?

Answer (score 0):

Your state will be in component props, just call console.log in constructor;

```
 console.log(props.groups)
```